# start-stop-daemon can't find executable that's right in front of it

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, start-stop-daemon

```
root@mountain-lion:/opt/smartfox# ls -lha
total 180K
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4.0K 2012-06-01 14:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K 2012-06-01 09:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4.0K 2009-05-17 21:57 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 2012-06-01 09:41 logs -> /var/opt/smartfox/logs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.4K 2012-06-01 14:28 run.sh


root@mountain-lion:/opt/smartfox# cat run.sh 
#!/bin/bash    
java -cp "./:./sfsExtensions/:lib/activation.jar:lib/commons-beanutils.jar:lib/commons-collections-3.2.jar:lib/commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar:lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar:lib/commons-pool-1.2.jar:lib/concurrent.jar:lib/ezmorph-1.0.3.jar:lib/h2.jar:lib/js.jar:lib/json-lib-2.1-jdk15.jar:lib/json.jar:lib/jsr173_1.0_api.jar:lib/jysfs.jar:lib/jython.jar:lib/nanoxml-2.2.1.jar:lib/wrapper.jar:lib/xbean.jar:lib/javamail/imap.jar:lib/javamail/mailapi.jar:lib/javamail/pop3.jar:lib/javamail/smtp.jar:lib/jetty/jetty.jar:lib/jetty/jetty-util.jar:lib/jetty/jstl.jar:lib/jetty/multipartrequest.jar:lib/jetty/servlet-api.jar:lib/jetty/standard.jar:lib/jsp-2.1/commons-el-1.0.jar:lib/jsp-2.1/core-3.1.0.jar:lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar:lib/jsp-2.1/jstl.jar:lib/jsp-2.1/standard.jar:lib/lsc.jar:lib/commons-io-1.4.jar" \
it.gotoandplay.smartfoxserver.SmartFoxServer > logs/smartfox.out 2>&1 &
JAVAPID=$!
echo "Started Smartfox. JVM PID = $JAVAPID"
trap "echo Stopping Smartfox.; kill $JAVAPID" INT TERM
wait
echo "Smartfox stopped."


root@mountain-lion:/opt/smartfox# start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/opt/smartfox/smartfox.pid --exec ./run.sh
start-stop-daemon: unable to start ./run.sh (No such file or directory)
```

Why can't `start-stop-daemon` find the script?

Answer (score 1):

Substituting `./run.sh` with `pwd` told me that it changes the directory to `/`. I suppose I need to change `./run.sh` into `/opt/smartfox/run.sh` and update the script to set its own directory.

Answer (score 1):

I find that it's better to avoid relative paths in starup scripts and the like. If things are getting confused, it's always best to be as explicit as possible - then you're not left guessing "I wonder what directory the process executing this script thinks is current".

This also goes for anything being run by cron. The environment cron is running under is different to the environment you are running in as a regular user.